# Java code API repositores

Tags: java, api, repository

Probably a silly question, but I wanted to give it a try anyway. I would need a Java repository, or something alike, where I can find the code where a specific Java API has been used. For example, I would like to find Java code where StringBuffer has been used frequently. The reason for this is so I could see how the API is used. Does such thing exists or something similar at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://grepcode.com/
It searches through open source code.